URL that creates a pre-populated SMS message to a contact
Is there a way to open a Google Messages URL such that an SMS message with a contact is started and pre-populated?
WhatsApp has functionality like that  they call 'Click to Chat' where you create a URL of the format:
https://wa.me/[contact_#]?text=[url_encoded_txt]

For example,
https://wa.me/14146867677?text=%20Hello%20world

Is there a variation that works in  Google Messages?
Something along the lines of:
https://messages.google.com/web/conversations?to=[contact_#]&text=[url_encoded_txt] 

